# UnrealEngine4: Recv function would keep blocking when TCP server shutdown

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, blocking, unreal-engine4

I use a **blocking FSocket** in client-side that connected to tcp server, if there's no message from server, socket thread would block in function **FScoket::Recv()**, if TCP server shutdown, socket thread is still blocking in this function. but when use blocking socket of **BSD Socket API**, thread would pass from **recv** function and return **errno** when TCP server shutdown, so is it the defect of FSocket?

```
uint32 HRecvThread::Run()
{
    uint8* recv_buf = new uint8[RECV_BUF_SIZE];

    uint8* const recv_buf_head = recv_buf;
    int readLenSeq = 0;

    while (Started)
    {
        //if (TcpClient->Connected() && ClientSocket->GetConnectionState() != SCS_Connected)
        //{
        //  // server disconnected
        //  TcpClient->SetConnected(false);
        //  break;
        //}

        int32 bytesRead = 0;
        //because use blocking socket, so thread would block in Recv function if have no message
        ClientSocket->Recv(recv_buf, readLenSeq, bytesRead);

        .....

        //some logic of resolution for tcp msg bytes

        .....
    }

    delete[] recv_buf;
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Don't call it when server is not responded with success

Comment: @Drop How exactly can he discover that the server didn't respond with success without trying to receive a response?

Comment: I mean that after client connect to server with success, then shutdown server manually.

Comment: @EJP Sorry for sloppy wording. You need to call this in UE API: [`FSocket::HasPendingData()`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Sockets/FSocket/HasPendingData/index.html) before trying to read from it. Despite it's name `FSocket` is not really a socket wrapper, it's more high-level entity convenient for simple gamedev applications.

Comment: @Protoss Show us your [code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) anyway. Maybe there is really something wrong with it or with UE.

Comment: @Drop thx very much, it doesn't matter, I would use BSD socket instead of UE4 FSocket.

Comment: @Drop Hard to believe you can't just receive. These pending-data methods aren't much use in practice: what do you do while there isn't? Sleep? For how long? Why? when a receive would block for exactly the right time?

Answer (score 1):

As I expected, you are ignoring the return code, which presumably indicates success or failure, so you are looping indefinitely (*not* blocking) on an error or end of stream condition.

NB You should allocate the `recv_buf` on the stack, not dynamically. Don't use the heap when you don't have to.

Comment: thx so much! because **recv_buf ** need 1MB memory, so I have to allocate on the heap

Comment: It probably doesn't. You won't get that much out of a single socket read. Have a look at the actual lengths you're getting back. You might get a surprise.

Comment: ok, I will try it later.thx again, your suggestion is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question on the forums in the UE4 C++ Programming section. Here is the discussion:

https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?111552-Recv-function-would-keep-blocking-when-TCP-server-shutdown

Long story short, in the UE4 Source, they ignore EWOULDBLOCK as an error. The code comments state that they do not view it as an error.

Also, there are several helper functions you should be using when opening the port and when polling the port (I assume you are polling since you are using blocking calls)

- `FSocket::Connect` returns a bool, so make sure to check that return
  value.
- `FSocket::GetLastError` returns the UE4 Translated error code if an
  error occured with the socket.
- `FSocket::HasPendingData` will return a value that informs you if it
  is safe to read from the socket.
- `FSocket::HasPendingConnection` can check to see your connection state.
- `FSocket::GetConnectionState` will tell you your active connection state.

Using these helper functions for error checking before making a call to `FSocket::Recv` will help you make sure you are in a good state before trying to read data. Also, it was noted in the forum posts that using the non-blocking code worked as expected. So, if you do not have a specific reason to use blocking code, just use the non-blocking implementation.

Also, as a final hint, using `FSocket::Wait` will block until your socket is in a desirable state of your choosing with a timeout, i.e. is readable or has data.